# SVG: transition , animation and then another transition doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

My goal here is to animate a rocket in my website.

It first take off then it moves a little bit on the spot on the top of the svg and then it take off for good, further. The two first steps are working well but the last one doesn't work. Maybe that's because i already assigned a transition at first to it. I achieve the first step by doing so:

```
$("#rocket", svgDoc).css({transform:"translateY(-720px)",transition:"6s"});
```

Then the second one is on the style part of svg file :

```
#rocket{
    animation: fly 1s infinite alternate;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fly {
100% {
    transform : translateY(-10px);
}
}

@keyframes fly {
100% {
    transform : translateY(-10px);
}   
}
```

Then the third one , i tried it by attribute it a new class but the transition doesn't work. the translate part works good but not the animation:

```
.byebye{
    transform : translateY(-400px);
    transition : transform 2s;
}
```

Any thoughts ?

Here is a jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/yptn6ovd/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suggest decouple animate phrases, maybe svg  tag better
still i made it work, rocket not showing in last phrase is a browser bug, need a time gap to fix it

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/postor/1oq2g7w3/1/)

```js
var svgDoc = $("#fusee")[0].contentDocument; // Get the document object for the SVG
    $("#all", svgDoc).css({transform:"translateY(-720px)",transition:"6s"});
    var nuages = $("#nuages");
    var fusee = $("#fusee");
    $("#nuages").fadeIn(9000);
    
    setTimeout(function(){
     fusee.addClass('fly');
    },6000);
    
    setTimeout( function() {
            fusee.removeClass('fly');
            setTimeout(function(){
            fusee.addClass("byebye");
            },50);//.addClass("byebye");
            $("#logo").fadeIn(3000);
            $("#bottom").css({transform:"translateY(-180px)", transition: "2s"});
       }, 10000);
```

```css
.st0{fill:#BF534F;}
 .st1{fill:#FFC843;}
 .st2{fill:#0071CE;}
 .st3{fill:#333E48;}
 .st4{fill:#08153a;}
 .st5{fill:#A4A9AD;}
 .st6{clip-path:url(#SVGID_2_);}
 .st7{clip-path:url(#SVGID_4_);fill:#F1F1F1;}
 .st8{clip-path:url(#SVGID_4_);fill:#E5E5E5;}
 .st9{clip-path:url(#SVGID_6_);}
 .st10{clip-path:url(#SVGID_8_);fill:#F1F1F1;}
 .st11{clip-path:url(#SVGID_8_);fill:#E5E5E5;}
 .st12{fill:#FFF200;}
 .st13{fill:#6E8DC8;}
 .st14{fill:#ED1C24;}
 .st15{fill:#FFFFFF;}
 #fusee{
  
 }
.fly{
  animation: fly 1s infinite alternate;
}
 .byebye{
  transform : translateY(-400px);
  transition : transform 2s;
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes fly {
   100% {
      transform : translateY(-10px);
   }
 }

 @keyframes fly {
   100% {
      transform : translateY(-10px);
   } 
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="-385.9 -215.9 625.5 976" style="enable-background:new -385.9 -215.9 625.5 976;" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="all">
 <g id="fusee">
  <path class="st0" d="M-52.2,707.8c2.9,0,20.5-1,23.9,14.5c2.7,12.2,3.6,18.7,12.3,18.7s12.4-7.3,8.7-29.5
   c-3-18.2-5.4-30.5-44.9-30.5L-52.2,707.8L-52.2,707.8z"/>
  <path class="st0" d="M-98.9,707.8c-2.9,0-20.5-1-23.9,14.5c-2.7,12.2-3.6,18.7-12.3,18.7c-8.7,0-12.4-7.3-8.7-29.5
   c3-18.2,5.4-30.5,44.9-30.5V707.8z"/>
  <g>
   <path class="st1" d="M-53.5,721.3c0-12.2-9.9-22.1-22.1-22.1s-22.1,9.9-22.1,22.1s9.9,38.8,22.1,38.8
    C-63.4,760.1-53.5,733.5-53.5,721.3z"/>
   <path class="st0" d="M-64.8,720.7c0-6-4.8-10.8-10.8-10.8s-10.8,4.8-10.8,10.8c0,6,4.8,19,10.8,19
    C-69.6,739.6-64.8,726.6-64.8,720.7z"/>
  </g>
  <path class="st2" d="M-45.1,713.8c7.6-28.7,14-77.5,14-97.6s-14.6-72-44.5-97.6c-29.9,25.6-44.5,77.5-44.5,97.6s6.5,68.9,14,97.6
   H-45.1L-45.1,713.8z"/>
  <path class="st3" d="M-111.1,690.9c1.6,8.3,3.3,16.1,5.1,22.8h60.9c1.8-6.7,3.5-14.5,5.1-22.8H-111.1z"/>
  <path class="st0" d="M-75.6,518.6c-9.9,8.5-18.2,19.9-24.8,32.1h49.5C-57.4,538.5-65.6,527.1-75.6,518.6z"/>
  <g>
   <path class="st15" d="M-64.9,639.7c0-11.6,14.6-14.8,14.6-34.1c0-14-11.3-25.3-25.3-25.3s-25.3,11.3-25.3,25.3
    c0,19.3,14.6,22.5,14.6,34.1H-64.9z"/>
   <path class="st5" d="M-87.6,644.1c0,6.7,5.4,12.1,12.1,12.1c6.7,0,12.1-5.4,12.1-12.1H-87.6z"/>
   <path class="st3" d="M-61.3,643c0-1.9-1.5-3.4-3.4-3.4h-21.8c-1.9,0-3.4,1.5-3.4,3.4v4.7c0,1.9,1.5,3.4,3.4,3.4h21.8
    c1.9,0,3.4-1.5,3.4-3.4L-61.3,643L-61.3,643z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="bottom">
  <g id="nuages" style="display:none;">
   <g>
    <defs>
     <polygon id="SVGID_1_" points="-389.2,1587 235.6,1582.4 230,1139.4 -394.7,1144      "/>
    </defs>
    <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
     <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"  style="overflow:visible;"/>
    </clipPath>
    <g class="st6">
     <defs>
      <polygon id="SVGID_3_" points="-389.2,1587 235.6,1582.4 230,1139.4 -394.7,1144       "/>
     </defs>
     <clipPath id="SVGID_4_">
      <use xlink:href="#SVGID_3_"  style="overflow:visible;"/>
     </clipPath>
     <path class="st7" d="M-119.2,1580l0.7,5l-0.5-5.1C-119,1580-119.1,1580-119.2,1580z"/>
     <path class="st7" d="M-110.3,1565.2l0.4,3.5l-0.3-4C-110.2,1564.9-110.3,1565.1-110.3,1565.2z"/>
     <path class="st7" d="M-69.3,1514.8l0.1,9.9l0.2-10.2C-69.1,1514.6-69.2,1514.7-69.3,1514.8z"/>
     <path class="st7" d="M-77.7,1523.2l0.2,7.2l0-7.4C-77.5,1523.1-77.6,1523.2-77.7,1523.2z"/>
     <path class="st7" d="M-16,1395.6c-0.4-0.1-0.8-0.1-1.2-0.3l0,0.2c0.4,1.3,0.7,2.7,1,4C-16.2,1398.2-16.1,1396.9-16,1395.6z"/>
     <path class="st7" d="M123.2,1184c-4,0-7.6,1.8-10.7,4.8c-26.5-15.3-98.4-25.9-182.8-25.3c-93.7,0.7-171.6,14.9-189.1,33.3
      c-2.3-0.7-4.8-1.1-7.3-1c-17.4,0.1-31.2,18.5-30.9,41.1c0.3,22.6,14.6,40.8,32,40.7c7.5-0.1,14.3-3.5,19.7-9.3
      c3.2,7.5,8.3,12.8,14.2,14.3c3.9,27.7,20.3,48.5,39.7,48.3c0.9,0,1.9-0.1,2.8-0.2c4,35.8,22.4,64.3,45.8,71.6l0.4,3.2
      c5.2-2.5,14.2-1.8,20.8-1.2c0.3-0.1,0.6-0.2,0.9-0.2l-0.1-1.2c16.3-4.4,30.1-19.2,38.4-39.7c0.3,0.2,0.7,0.3,1,0.5l0.1,3.2
      c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.6-0.3c1.4-0.6,2.8-1,4.2-1.2l0-0.2c0.3,0,0.6,0.1,0.9,0.1c1.3-0.2,2.5-0.1,3.6,0c0.3,0,0.6-0.1,0.8-0.1
      c0.7-0.6,1.7-1.1,3-1.3c1.2-0.2,2.3-0.3,3.4-0.4l0-0.6c8-4.6,14-15.2,15.8-28.2c4.4,3.7,9.5,5.8,14.9,5.7
      c2.4,0,4.8-0.5,7.1-1.3l0,0.8c0.3-0.2,0.7-0.4,1.1-0.6c1.6-0.8,3.7-0.8,5.5-0.3c0.5-0.9,1.5-1.7,2.7-2.2l0.3-4
      c1.8-1.9,3.5-4.1,5.1-6.5l-0.6,9.8c0.7,0.1,1.3,0.3,2,0.5c3,1.3,5.2,3.3,6.7,5.7l0.4-4.1c8,16.1,20.8,26.5,35.1,26.4
      c23.8-0.2,42.8-29.4,42.3-65.3c-0.1-8.3-1.3-16.3-3.2-23.6c4.2,3.3,8.9,5.1,13.9,5.1c15.8-0.1,28.4-18.9,28.8-42.3
      c3.3,3.6,7.4,5.6,11.7,5.6c11-0.1,19.7-13.6,19.5-30.1C143.3,1197.2,134.2,1183.9,123.2,1184z M-159.1,1239.7
      c-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.3-0.8c0.4,0,0.8,0.1,1.1,0.1C-158.6,1239.3-158.9,1239.5-159.1,1239.7z"/>
     <path class="st7" d="M-28.3,1578.4l-0.4,5.9l0.6-6.1C-28.2,1578.3-28.2,1578.4-28.3,1578.4z"/>
     <path class="st8" d="M-339.5,1143.6l510.6-3.7c2.5,5.5,3.9,11.5,4,17.9c0.3,25.5-21.1,46.3-47.8,46.5c-4.5,0-8.8-0.5-13-1.6
      c-2.7,25.3-16.9,44.7-34.3,44.8c-2.2,0-4.3-0.3-6.3-0.8c-7.5,25.3-25.3,43.2-46.3,43.3c-17.9,0.1-33.7-12.6-43.1-31.9
      c-4.4,4.5-9.7,7.1-15.5,7.2c-11.4,0.1-21.3-9.9-25.7-24.3c-13.6,22.4-34.3,36.7-57.7,36.8c-29.1,0.2-54.6-21.6-67.7-53.7
      c-4.8,4.8-10.4,7.5-16.4,7.6c-9.2,0.1-17.5-6.1-23.4-16.1c-10.6,16.3-28.3,27.1-48.3,27.2c-33,0.2-60.1-28.2-60.6-63.5
      c-0.1-7.7,1.1-15.1,3.3-21.9C-333.2,1153.3-337.2,1148.7-339.5,1143.6"/>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <defs>
     <rect id="SVGID_5_" x="-391.9" y="708.1" width="624.8" height="443"/>
    </defs>
    <clipPath id="SVGID_6_">
     <use xlink:href="#SVGID_5_"  style="overflow:visible;"/>
    </clipPath>
    <g class="st9">
     <defs>
      <rect id="SVGID_7_" x="-391.9" y="708.1" width="624.8" height="443"/>
     </defs>
     <clipPath id="SVGID_8_">
      <use xlink:href="#SVGID_7_"  style="overflow:visible;"/>
     </clipPath>
     <path class="st10" d="M125.5,1047.4c-4.4,0-8.4,2.1-11.7,5.7c-0.7-23.5-13.6-42.1-29.4-42.1c-5,0-9.7,1.9-13.8,5.2
      c1.9-7.3,2.9-15.3,2.9-23.6c0-35.9-19.3-65-43.1-65c-14.3,0-27,10.5-34.8,26.6l-27.1-246.1l18.8,258.1
      c-1.6-2.4-3.3-4.6-5.2-6.4l-22.4-235.5l12.8,229.2c-2.3-0.8-4.6-1.3-7.1-1.3c-5.4,0-10.4,2.1-14.8,5.8
      c-1.9-12.9-8-23.5-16.1-28l-5.9-162l1,160.1c-1.4-0.3-2.8-0.5-4.2-0.5c-0.9,0-1.8,0.1-2.7,0.2l-2.4-165.4L-82,929.3
      c-0.3,0.2-0.7,0.3-1,0.5c-8.5-20.4-22.5-35.1-38.9-39.4l9.4-166.1L-130,889.2c-0.6,0-1.2,0-1.8,0c-1.2,0-2.3,0.1-3.5,0.2
      l14.1-181.2L-143.9,891c-23.3,7.5-41.3,36.1-44.9,71.9c-0.9-0.1-1.9-0.2-2.8-0.2c-19.4,0-35.5,20.9-39.1,48.6
      c-5.8,1.5-10.9,6.9-14,14.4c-5.4-5.7-12.3-9.1-19.8-9.1c-17.4,0-31.4,18.3-31.4,40.9c0,22.6,14.1,40.9,31.4,40.9
      c2.5,0,4.9-0.4,7.2-1.1c17.7,18.2,95.8,31.9,189.5,31.9c84.4,0,156.2-11.1,182.5-26.6c3.1,3,6.8,4.7,10.7,4.7
      c11,0,19.9-13.4,19.9-30C145.4,1060.9,136.5,1047.4,125.5,1047.4 M-157.9,1054.4c0.1-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.3-0.8
      c0.3,0.2,0.5,0.4,0.8,0.6C-157.1,1054.4-157.5,1054.4-157.9,1054.4"/>
     <path class="st11" d="M-336.8,1151.1h510.6c2.4-5.5,3.8-11.6,3.8-17.9c0-25.5-21.7-46.2-48.4-46.2c-4.5,0-8.8,0.6-12.9,1.7
      c-3-25.3-17.5-44.5-34.9-44.5c-2.2,0-4.3,0.3-6.3,0.9c-7.8-25.3-25.9-43-46.9-43c-17.9,0-33.6,12.8-42.7,32.2
      c-4.4-4.5-9.8-7.1-15.6-7.1c-11.4,0-21.2,10.1-25.4,24.5c-13.9-22.3-34.8-36.4-58.1-36.4c-29.1,0-54.4,22-67.1,54.2
      c-4.8-4.7-10.5-7.4-16.5-7.4c-9.2,0-17.4,6.2-23.2,16.2c-10.8-16.2-28.6-26.9-48.7-26.9c-33,0-59.8,28.6-59.8,64
      c0,7.7,1.3,15,3.6,21.9C-330.6,1141.3-334.5,1146-336.8,1151.1"/>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
  <g id="logo" style="display:none">
   <g>
    <polygon class="st4" points="-256,1116.5 -247.7,1098.8 -257.7,1098.8 -267.7,1098.8 -259.4,1116.5 -270.7,1165.5 -257.7,1207 
     -244.7,1165.5     "/>
    <g>
     <path class="st12" d="M-226.2,1214.1c14,0,18.2-3.3,18.2-11.6v-32.7c0-10.1,0.3-13.6,9.4-18.7c-7.8-4.4-9.4-9.2-9.4-18.5v-32.9
      c0-8.3-4.3-11.6-18.2-11.6v-6.8c0,0,8.9,0,11.6,0.4c11.8,1.5,14.5,11.1,14.5,21.4v29.7c0,6.7,0.2,10,7.2,14.6l5.4,3.7l-5.3,2.5
      c-9,4.4-7.2,10.2-7.2,16.9v28.5c0,10.3-2.6,19.9-14.5,21.4c-2.6,0.4-11.6,0.4-11.6,0.4V1214.1z"/>
     <path class="st13" d="M-226.2,1214.1c14,0,18.2-3.3,18.2-11.6v-32.7c0-10.1,0.3-13.6,9.4-18.7c-7.8-4.4-9.4-9.2-9.4-18.5v-32.9
      c0-8.3-4.3-11.6-18.2-11.6v-6.8c0,0,8.9,0,11.6,0.4c11.8,1.5,14.5,11.1,14.5,21.4v29.7c0,6.7,0.2,10,7.2,14.6l5.4,3.7l-5.3,2.5
      c-9,4.4-7.2,10.2-7.2,16.9v28.5c0,10.3-2.6,19.9-14.5,21.4c-2.6,0.4-11.6,0.4-11.6,0.4V1214.1z"/>
     <path class="st14" d="M-289.2,1220.9c0,0-8.9,0-11.6-0.4c-11.8-1.5-14.5-11.1-14.5-21.4v-28.5c0-6.8,1.8-12.5-7.2-16.9
      l-5.3-2.5l5.4-3.7c7-4.7,7.2-8,7.2-14.6v-29.7c0-10.3,2.6-19.9,14.5-21.4c2.6-0.4,11.6-0.4,11.6-0.4v6.8
      c-14,0-18.2,3.3-18.2,11.6v32.9c0,9.3-1.6,14.1-9.4,18.5c9.2,5.2,9.4,8.7,9.4,18.7v32.7c0,8.3,4.3,11.6,18.2,11.6V1220.9z"/>
     <path class="st13" d="M-289.2,1220.9c0,0-8.9,0-11.6-0.4c-11.8-1.5-14.5-11.1-14.5-21.4v-28.5c0-6.8,1.8-12.5-7.2-16.9
      l-5.3-2.5l5.4-3.7c7-4.7,7.2-8,7.2-14.6v-29.7c0-10.3,2.6-19.9,14.5-21.4c2.6-0.4,11.6-0.4,11.6-0.4v6.8
      c-14,0-18.2,3.3-18.2,11.6v32.9c0,9.3-1.6,14.1-9.4,18.5c9.2,5.2,9.4,8.7,9.4,18.7v32.7c0,8.3,4.3,11.6,18.2,11.6V1220.9z"/>
     <path class="st4" d="M-136.2,1138.5v4c-2.1-1.8-4.5-2.7-7.4-2.7c-3.1,0-5.7,1.1-7.8,3.4c-2.1,2.2-3.2,4.9-3.2,8.1
      c0,3.1,1.1,5.7,3.2,8c2.1,2.2,4.7,3.4,7.8,3.4c2.8,0,5.3-1,7.4-2.9v4.1c-2.2,1.3-4.7,2-7.3,2c-4,0-7.4-1.4-10.3-4.2
      c-2.9-2.8-4.3-6.2-4.3-10.2c0-4.1,1.4-7.6,4.3-10.4c2.9-2.8,6.4-4.3,10.5-4.3C-140.6,1136.6-138.3,1137.3-136.2,1138.5"/>
     <path class="st4" d="M-122.3,1140.9c2.9-2.9,6.3-4.3,10.3-4.3c4,0,7.4,1.4,10.3,4.3c2.9,2.9,4.3,6.3,4.3,10.3
      c0,4.1-1.4,7.6-4.3,10.4c-2.8,2.8-6.3,4.2-10.4,4.2s-7.5-1.4-10.4-4.2c-2.8-2.8-4.3-6.2-4.3-10.4
      C-126.6,1147.2-125.2,1143.8-122.3,1140.9 M-119.8,1159.2c2.2,2.2,4.8,3.3,7.9,3.3c3,0,5.7-1.1,7.9-3.3c2.2-2.2,3.3-4.9,3.3-8
      c0-3.1-1.1-5.8-3.2-8c-2.1-2.2-4.8-3.3-8-3.3c-3.2,0-5.9,1.1-8,3.3c-2.1,2.2-3.2,4.9-3.2,8
      C-123.1,1154.4-122,1157-119.8,1159.2"/>
     <path class="st4" d="M-86.8,1165.2v-27.9h5.8c4.5,0,8.3,1.2,11.2,3.6c3,2.4,4.4,5.8,4.4,10.2c0,4.6-1.5,8.1-4.4,10.5
      c-2.9,2.4-6.7,3.6-11.4,3.6H-86.8z M-83.4,1140.4v21.6h1.2c1.9,0,3.6-0.2,5.1-0.6c1.5-0.4,2.9-1,4.2-1.8
      c1.2-0.8,2.2-1.9,2.9-3.4c0.7-1.4,1.1-3.1,1.1-5.1c0-2-0.4-3.7-1.1-5.1c-0.7-1.4-1.7-2.6-2.9-3.4c-1.3-0.8-2.6-1.4-4.2-1.8
      c-1.5-0.4-3.2-0.6-5.1-0.6H-83.4z"/>
     <polygon class="st4" points="-54.5,1165.2 -54.5,1137.2 -39.5,1137.2 -39.5,1140.4 -51,1140.4 -51,1148.2 -39.8,1148.2 
      -39.8,1151.4 -51,1151.4 -51,1162 -39.5,1162 -39.5,1165.2      "/>
     <rect x="-9.8" y="1137.2" class="st13" width="3.5" height="27.9"/>
     <polygon class="st13" points="6,1165.2 6,1135.9 27,1157.9 27,1137.2 30.5,1137.2 30.5,1166.3 9.5,1144.3 9.5,1165.2      "/>
     <path class="st13" d="M58,1140.9l-2.8,1.7c-1-1.8-2.5-2.6-4.5-2.6c-1.2,0-2.3,0.4-3.2,1.1c-1,0.7-1.4,1.7-1.4,2.9
      c0,1.7,1.3,3,3.9,4l2,0.8c2.2,0.9,3.9,1.9,5.1,3.2c1.2,1.3,1.8,3,1.8,5.2c0,2.5-0.9,4.6-2.6,6.2c-1.7,1.6-3.8,2.5-6.4,2.5
      c-2.2,0-4.2-0.7-5.8-2.2c-1.6-1.5-2.6-3.3-2.9-5.6l3.5-0.7c0,1.5,0.5,2.8,1.5,3.8c1,1,2.3,1.5,3.9,1.5c1.5,0,2.7-0.5,3.7-1.6
      c1-1.1,1.5-2.4,1.5-3.8c0-1.4-0.4-2.4-1.3-3.2c-0.9-0.8-2-1.5-3.5-2.1l-1.9-0.8c-1.9-0.8-3.4-1.8-4.5-2.8
      c-1.1-1.1-1.6-2.5-1.6-4.3c0-2.2,0.8-3.9,2.4-5.2c1.6-1.3,3.6-2,5.8-2C54,1136.6,56.4,1138,58,1140.9"/>
     <rect x="70" y="1137.2" class="st13" width="3.5" height="27.9"/>
     <path class="st13" d="M85.9,1165.2v-27.9h5.8c4.5,0,8.3,1.2,11.2,3.6c3,2.4,4.4,5.8,4.4,10.2c0,4.6-1.5,8.1-4.4,10.5
      c-2.9,2.4-6.7,3.6-11.4,3.6H85.9z M89.3,1140.4v21.6h1.2c1.9,0,3.6-0.2,5.1-0.6c1.5-0.4,2.9-1,4.2-1.8c1.2-0.8,2.2-1.9,2.9-3.4
      c0.7-1.4,1.1-3.1,1.1-5.1c0-2-0.4-3.7-1.1-5.1c-0.7-1.4-1.7-2.6-2.9-3.4c-1.3-0.8-2.6-1.4-4.2-1.8c-1.5-0.4-3.2-0.6-5.1-0.6
      H89.3z"/>
     <polygon class="st13" points="118.2,1165.2 118.2,1137.2 133.2,1137.2 133.2,1140.4 121.7,1140.4 121.7,1148.2 132.9,1148.2 
      132.9,1151.4 121.7,1151.4 121.7,1162 133.2,1162 133.2,1165.2      "/>
     <path class="st13" d="M153.5,1153l8.8,12.2h-4.2l-8.2-11.8h-1.4v11.8h-3.5v-27.9h4.2c1.1,0,1.9,0,2.6,0.1
      c0.7,0,1.4,0.2,2.4,0.4c0.9,0.2,1.7,0.5,2.4,0.9c1.1,0.7,2,1.6,2.7,2.8c0.7,1.2,1,2.5,1,3.9c0,2-0.6,3.8-1.9,5.2
      C157.1,1151.9,155.5,1152.8,153.5,1153 M148.4,1140.3v10.1h1.1c1,0,1.9-0.1,2.7-0.2c0.8-0.1,1.5-0.4,2.3-0.7
      c0.8-0.3,1.4-0.9,1.8-1.6c0.4-0.7,0.6-1.6,0.6-2.7c0-3.3-2.5-5-7.6-5H148.4z"/>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not getting the third part after watching the fiddle.. However, try

Put this inside a class

```
{transform:"translateY(-720px)",transition:"6s"}
```

and remove that class before adding `byebye` class to element.

Comment: So the class style would be : takeoff{ transform: translateY(-720px); transition: transform 6s;}?

Comment: Well, this dosen't worked ... I tired.. 
Not able to visualize actually animation ..how you want.. Check this once https://jsfiddle.net/yptn6ovd/3/

Comment: The problem is, in your answer, when i remove the class, it goes in the bottom before doing the new transition..

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `animation:infinite` looping from your #fusee. Even you can remove `animation-direction:alternate` as we don't want it to perform reverse action. Mainly animation loop was creating that issue.

```
#fusee{
    animation: fly 1s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
```